# What is the relationship between gwmi and Get-WmiObject

Tags: powershell

After reading around, I'm confused about the relationship between these.  I don't believe `gwmi` is a pure alias for `Get-WmiObject`, as they seem to share similar but not identical syntax in the examples I've seen.

Interestingly enough, when I google "gwmi" on its own, all the top references immediately refer back to  `Get-WmiObject` but don't seem to reference `gwmi` itself.

Comment: Not sure what more evidence you are looking for? Aliases are a simple mechanic. `get-alias gwmi` and do not change the cmdlet called. Meerly create a shortcut for its ease of use. Do you have examples of the contrary?

Comment: What "not identical syntax" have you seen that has confused you?

Comment: So of course I was way off what threw me was that I was looking at two different examples, one using -filter as a parameter one using -query and some other syntactic differences.   But thanks to all the posters, I not only the answer , but the exact way to find all needed info about aliases that I could not locate before.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no fancy voodoo at work here. Aliases in PowerShell are a *very* simple mechanic that help with short hand coding. Unix aliases, on the other hand, are different and can include entire command calls (Which could possibly be a source of confusion?).

In all cases, there is nothing more that just what you see here from `Get-Alias`

```
PS C:\Users\Bagel> get-alias gwmi

CommandType     Name                                               ModuleName                                                      
-----------     ----                                               ----------                                                      
Alias           gwmi -> Get-WmiObject
```

If you have evidence to the contrary I am sure the community would love to see it!

Answer (score 1):

The authoritative reference you need to clear this up is [about_Aliases](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847830.aspx):

> An alias is an alternate name or nickname for a cmdlet or for a command element, such as a function, script, file, or executable file. You can use the alias instead of the command name in any Windows PowerShellcommands.